# Outlet covers no longer fit

Tags: receptacle, kitchens, tile

I installed a backsplash in my kitchen, after finishing the job I realized that the outlet covers no longer fit due since they are flush with the wall as opposed to slightly sticking out. Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 6):

A photo would be helpful, but from your description it sounds like you need a box extension. This extends the box so your receptacles stand proud (above) of the surface and will allow the cover to fit properly. I use these quite often after a tile job where they did not reset the boxes prior to tiling. If it is a slight setback you can loosen the receptacles and pull them to the cover if 2 screw would be ok by code, there are plastic shims that go behind the tabs on the receptacles with only 1 screw to the cover so the covers don’t break but this is for ~1/8-1/4” set back more would need an extension.

Comment: Just finished installing three of the metal single gang extenders in my kitchen after tiling my back splash.  The  GFCI outlet just barely fit, wrapped a few rounds of electrical tape around it..+

Comment: With extenders a few wraps of tape is a great idea.

Answer (score 5):

The maximum depth allowed by Code on a non-combustible surface is 1/4", if deeper you need something like a [box extender](https://amzn.to/2YiSWnY). If your problem is just that the wings of the device miss the tile but you are still within legal clearance you can use a [leveling clip](https://amzn.to/2KJ4etR) or [caterpillar shims](https://amzn.to/3f1L1kJ).

Comment: "allowed by Code on a" *combustible* surface (i.e., drywall) is 1/4". I don't think tile, thinset, and backerboard count as combustible. - I've never seen leveling clips, +1

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the point of a box extender if it's made out of plastic, but I live in Chicago's EMT land where everything is metal. I was going to say it's a little late to extend the box (with a mud ring). And I don't see why you'd shove a piece of plastic in between stuff that's even less flammable.

Comment: @Mazura 314.20 Installations within or behind a surface of concrete, tile, gypsum, plaster, or other noncombustible material, boxes employing a ﬂush-type cover or faceplate shall be made so that the front edge of the box, plaster ring, extension ring, or listed extender will not be set back of the ﬁnished surface more than 6 mm (1⁄4 in.). In walls and ceilings constructed of wood or other combustible surface material, boxes, plaster rings, extension rings, or listed extenders shall be ﬂush with the ﬁnished surface or project therefrom.